# How to insert delay in trow generator in talend

Tags: talend

I am new to talend.I am using trow generator to prepare test data and pushing it to kafka topic.
I am using trowgenerator->tmap->twritejsonfield->data_type_conversion->kafkaoutput.
Now i want to add some delay while getting data from row generator to kafka for every 100 records.

I used tsleep,but im getting delay for every record.

How to achieve this,please help me out

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your job with the tSleep, please ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible with your generator, you can use a loop with delay and generate 100 row each time :

tloop -> tsleep -> trowgenerator -> tmap -> ...

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But i want to generate 1 crore rows with unique column.For example,I want to generate data of 1 crore from emp_id "1" to emp_id "10000000".if I generate 100 rows each time,Then I get emp_id 1-100 only everytime in everyloop.